# What is the use case of merge vs mergeFields

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Can anyone actually explain, in layman's terms, what is a real-world use case for the `set` operation's options?

While I fully understand what `set with merge` does, as well as `merge` beeing a `boolean` and `mergeFields` being an `array` of `fieldPaths`, I cannot think of cases in which `mergeFields` might be of any use.

I also understand the fact that `mergeFields` basically acts like a `mask` for the `object` passed to the `set` operation, but I still cannot think of how is it so useful that it actually got implemented within the SDK.

Can someone shed some light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through the documentation, there seem to be two reasons why you might want to use one vs the other:

1. `mergeFieldPaths`/`mergeFields` trigger an error when passing in field values that don't currently exist on the document while `merge` will add in those fields if they don't exist. The error is good for safety purposes if you're concerned about typos/writing to incorrect field paths.
2. This one is just a guess, but the documentation indicates `mergeFieldPaths`/`mergeFields` ignores **AND** leaves fields untouched while merge **ONLY** leaves other fields untouched. It's possible there's some performance advantage to using `mergeFieldPaths`/`mergeFields` esp for documents with a ton of fields. The difference might be direct access vs still needing to look at unspecified fields to identify the matches in some way.

[SetOptions Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/SetOptions)